# Handling a subgroup of $S_{6}$

Tags: group-theory

I came across with the following question:

Let $H=\{\sigma \in S_6 | \sigma(x) \textrm{ is odd if and only if } x \textrm{ is odd}\}$. Prove that $H$ has a normal subgroup $Y$ so $[H : Y ]=4$.

How should I prove this theorem?

Comment: Try to understand $H$ a little. For example, what is its order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll separate the steps into spoilers so you can use them as hints

The set $H$:

> First we need to understand the set $H$, we know that a permutation in $Sym(6)$ moves points in the set $\Omega:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Now, $H$ is defined to be the set of points which fix the subset $\Lambda:=\{1,3,5\}$ of odd integers setwise.

The group $H$:

> The elements of $Sym(6)$ which fix $\Lambda$ setwise are exactly the permutations that permute elements of $\Lambda$, that is, $Sym(\Lambda)=Sym(\{1,3,5\})$ and the elements which permute $\Gamma:=\{2,4,6\}$, these are exactly the elements in $Sym(\Gamma)$.  Since no element of $\Gamma$ can be sent to an element of $\Lambda$ we conclude $H$ is the direct product $Sym(\Lambda)\times Sym(\Gamma)\cong Sym(3)\times Sym(3)$.

The normal subgroup:

> First we recall that $Sym(3)$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $C_3:=\mathbb{Z}_3$ so we deduce that $N_1:=\langle(135)\rangle$ is normal in $Sym(\Lambda)$ and $N_2:=\langle(246)\rangle$ is normal in $Sym(\Gamma)$.  As these are normal subgroups in different factors of the direct product we conclude there is a normal subgroup $N:=N_1\times N_2$ in $H$.

The order:

> A quick calculation gives $|H|=6*6=36$ and $|N|=3*3=9$.  Therefore $|H:N|=4$.

Comment: Great, thank you! How to compute $[S_6 : G \cap  A_6]$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for permutations of $H$, you can separate their action on odd and even integers. Thus $H \cong S_3 \times S_3$.